# In Python/SQLite3, How does one define a variable to be used to query a database table?

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, bcrypt

I have a table with three columns

```
  id  username  password
  ----------------------
  1  Jdoe      $2a$12$sv97wrhscHkKVMZ8P/2yw.O/cz8pWUE/1zlTyFNJ9.jCYhR8Nw9Iu
  2  user      $2a$12$dLeSlYFyPdP1WhA4Tw21ZuX5v5XH55.yK2XApMd4VglUDRJEd4Lmy
```

My aim is to authenticate user based on the password provided at login. To achieve this I have written Python code that looks like this:

```
from bcrypt import hashpw, gensalt


if request.method == 'POST':
      if form.validate() == False:

         return render_template('login.html', form = form)
      else:
         #return render_template('index.html')
         password = request.form['password']
         password = hashpw(password, gensalt())
         con = sql.connect("testDB.db")
         cur = con.cursor()
         cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable where password =?", (password,))

         if cur.fetchall():
              return "welcome guest"
         else:
              return "user not found"
```

However when I enter an existing password the system returns the message "user not found". The desired output is for the message "Welcome guest".The `hashpw` and `gensalt()` are imported from `bcrypt`.

I am pretty sure I am defining the variable "password" wrongly. How does one properly define such a variable?

Comment: At first glance your password column looks farrrrr too narrow. I don't know what hash function you are using here, but most password hashes produce much longer hashes. Check your column width with the hash length

Comment: Where did `hashpw` come from? Are you **certain** that the output that it produces matches the database column information? Also, you are generating a **new** salt, which is almost certainly the wrong thing to do. Normally you'd match the *username* against the database, retrieve the hashed password, and pass that together with the plaintext entered password to a different function that validates the password (by taking the salt from the hashed value, then hashing the plaintext with the *same salt* and comparing the result, in a cryptographically secure manner (defeating timing attacks)).

Comment: (If this is bcrypt, use `bcrypt.checkpw()` to compare entered password with the hash from the database, you *can't* use the entered password to locate the user in the database because you *do not have the salt used when you inserted the data in the database*).

Comment: @Martijn and @e4c5 i have included the real hashed passwords. The `hashpw` is imported from `bcrypt`. No i am not generating a new salt. After removing the salted password i still get the same undesired message.

Comment: @tapeli: please update your question to include that information, show where `hashpw` and `gensalt` come from. Without evidence to the contrary, `gensalt()` looks like it generates a new salt.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating a *new hash*, one with a totally different salt:

```
password = hashpw(password, gensalt())
```

You can't look up users by password; the whole point of using a salted hash is to make the impossible for hackers to use a rainbow table (common passwords hashed, but without a salt) to match hashes. That same protection makes it impossible for you to know, up-front, what salt was used for a given user, and you are almost guaranteed to be generating a different hash from your new salt.

You need to use the *username* to look up the right now, retrieve the salted password, then ask the `bcrypt.checkpw()` function to *securely* test the password against the stored hash. The hash value includes the salt, `bcrypt` will extract the salt and use it to verify that the same hash is generated. The comparison needs to protect against timing attacks, don't re-implement this check yourself.

Your form needs to send along the username, not just the password:

```
from bcrypt import checkpw


username = request.form['username']
password = request.form['password']
con = sql.connect("testDB.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT password FROM mytable where username = ?", (username,))
hashed = cur.fetchone()
if hashed is None or not checkpw(password, hashed[0]):
    # no such user, *or* the password did not match
    return "user not found"

# password matched the hashed value from the database
return "welcome guest"
```